# Why does Firebug delay console output?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firebug, firephp

I have a simple promise based `$.ajax` post loop. The code works as expected, so I am just curious. (All data is shown in the console after the `done()` function was executed). However Firebug displays data from the PHP script after the output of the `done()` method. Why is this? Does Firebug do something while the code continues to run?

jQuery

```
var promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < tochange.length; i++) {
  var promise = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"updateLevel.php",
    data: { graph_plot: tochange[i], new_plot:changeto[i]}
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });

  promises.push(promise);
}

$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
  console.log('All done')
});
```

PHP

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../services/FirePHP.class.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../services/fb.php');

ob_start();

$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
$graph_plot = $_POST['graph_plot'];
$new_plot = $_POST['new_plot'];

if ($graph_plot && $new_plot) {
  fb("$graph_plot, $new_plot");
}
```

Comment: Weird indeed. Have you tested in Chrome?

Comment: I know right. I haven't. I do not have firebug installed on chrome, but i will get it and post the result.

Comment: I have installed firebug light on chrome, but cannot seem to find a way of using the fb() function any ideas?

Comment: You don't need anything else in Chrome. Just press F12. Tadaaaa

Comment: i have the firebug screen up, but on firefox there is a function to write to the firebug console "fb()". this is not writing to the chrome firebug console. so i can't test if the delay is there

Comment: No idea what fb() does in Firebug. Uninstall Firebug lite from Chrome, you don't need it.  Just press F12 to get Chrome's own debugger, which I personally much prefer to Firebug. Firebug lite is a javascript emulation of Firebug, that may be why it gives you wrong results on promises.

Comment: You are obviously using the [FirePHP](http://firephp.org/) extension for Firebug. You should add that information to you question. Note that the `fb()` function is coming from FirePHP. Also, you should append a screenshot of what you see and write down the console output you expect, so it's easier to understand what you mean.